# ASP .NET Core Identity custom ApiAuthorizationDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm working with ASP .NET Core 3.0 with Angular project. I see this new `ApiAuthorizationDbContext` and I wanted to override the table name and user id (to int) but there is no way I can do it. Does any body know a trick?

This is the class for the context to override the table name but it creates `AspNetUser` and `User` table. Why doesn't it just create one as usual?

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(
            DbContextOptions options,
            IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>(entity => { entity.ToTable(name: "User"); });
            modelBuilder.Entity<AppRole>(entity => { entity.ToTable(name: "Role"); });
        }
    }
```

Here is my user:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

Normaly I override the primary key with `AppUser<int>` but it doesn't work because of the `ApiAuthorizationDbContext`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For custom the user and role tables with `ApiAuthorizationDbContext`, you could follow steps below:

1. Create an Asp.Net Core Angular Template with Identity
2. Add User and Role Class

   ```
   public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
   {
   }
   public class AppRole : IdentityRole<int>
   {
   }
   ```
3. Add custom `ApiAuthorizationDbContext`

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Database abstraction for a combined <see cref="DbContext"/> using ASP.NET Identity and Identity Server.
   /// </summary>
   /// <typeparam name="TUser"></typeparam>
   /// <typeparam name="TRole"></typeparam>
   /// <typeparam name="TKey">Key of the IdentityUser entity</typeparam>
   public class KeyApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey> : IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey>, IPersistedGrantDbContext
       where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>
       where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey>
       where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
   {
       private readonly IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> _operationalStoreOptions;

       /// <summary>
       /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="ApiAuthorizationDbContext{TUser, TRole, TKey}"/>.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="options">The <see cref="DbContextOptions"/>.</param>
       /// <param name="operationalStoreOptions">The <see cref="IOptions{OperationalStoreOptions}"/>.</param>
       public KeyApiAuthorizationDbContext(
           DbContextOptions options,
           IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions)
           : base(options)
       {
           _operationalStoreOptions = operationalStoreOptions;
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{PersistedGrant}"/>.
       /// </summary>
       public DbSet<PersistedGrant> PersistedGrants { get; set; }

       /// <summary>
       /// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{DeviceFlowCodes}"/>.
       /// </summary>
       public DbSet<DeviceFlowCodes> DeviceFlowCodes { get; set; }

       Task<int> IPersistedGrantDbContext.SaveChangesAsync() => base.SaveChangesAsync();

       /// <inheritdoc />
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           builder.ConfigurePersistedGrantContext(_operationalStoreOptions.Value);
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Database abstraction for a combined <see cref="DbContext"/> using ASP.NET Identity and Identity Server.
   /// </summary>
   /// <typeparam name="TUser"></typeparam>
   public class ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser> : KeyApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser, IdentityRole, string>
       where TUser : IdentityUser
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="ApiAuthorizationDbContext{TUser}"/>.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="options">The <see cref="DbContextOptions"/>.</param>
       /// <param name="operationalStoreOptions">The <see cref="IOptions{OperationalStoreOptions}"/>.</param>
       public ApiAuthorizationDbContext(
           DbContextOptions options,
           IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions)
           : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
4. Change `DbContext`

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : KeyApiAuthorizationDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(
           DbContextOptions options,
           IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
       {
       }
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

           modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>(entity => { entity.ToTable(name: "User"); });
           modelBuilder.Entity<AppRole>(entity => { entity.ToTable(name: "Role"); });
       }
   }
   ```
5. Register user and role

   ```
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>()
       .AddRoles<AppRole>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

   services.AddIdentityServer()                
       .AddApiAuthorization<AppUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
   ```
6. Delete existing `Migrations`(if database exist, you may need to delete it).
7. Run add-migration and update-database to check the result.

Currently, you need to custom `ApiAuthorizationDbContext`, this issue has been tracked through [ApiAuthorizationDbContext force TUser to extends IdentityUser instead of IdentityUser #9548](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9548) and [Add IdentityUser support to ApiAuthorizationDbContext #13064](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/13064). It will be some delay to get the neweast version.

Comment: This is a great answer, and does exactly what I need - particularly useful as the MSFT guys have said they're not going to support a built-in class that does this. Two questions from me: 1) Since this adds a parameterized constructor, is there any way to still write code where I do `var db = new ApplicationDbContext(); db.Add( ... ); db.SaveChangesAsync()`? Or do I have to always inject a DbContext via DI now? And 2) Does anyone have a sample hosted Blazor Wasm project using this that I can look at to sanity check that my implementation is valid? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see ApiAuthorizationDbContext just implements IPersistedGrantDbContext. Looks like a templates class

To use custom keys I have implemented IPersistedGrantDbContext in my ApplicationDbContext see below.

Remember to call modelBuilder.ConfigurePersistedGrantContext(_OperationalStoreOptions.Value); on ModelCreating as shown below

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
    ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationRoleClaim,
    ApplicationUserToken>,
    IPersistedGrantDbContext
{
    private readonly IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> _OperationalStoreOptions;

    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options)
    {
        this._OperationalStoreOptions = operationalStoreOptions;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies(true);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{PersistedGrant}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<PersistedGrant> PersistedGrants { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{DeviceFlowCodes}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<DeviceFlowCodes> DeviceFlowCodes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{Key}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<Key> Keys { get; set; }

    Task<int> IPersistedGrantDbContext.SaveChangesAsync() => base.SaveChangesAsync();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ConfigurePersistedGrantContext(_OperationalStoreOptions.Value);
    }
}


 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    [Required]
    public Guid ApplicationUserRecordId { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>
{
    public ApplicationRole()
    {

    }
    public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<int>
{

}

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
{

}

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{

}
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{

}

public class ApplicationUserToken : IdentityUserToken<int>
{

}
```