# ApiAuthorizationDbContext PrimaryKey to int

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to change primary key of AspNetUsers from string to int.

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
        {
            public short FactoryId { get; set; }
            public Factory Factory { get; set; }
        }
```

But compiler is not happy about it:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>{

}
```

it says:

type 'Domain.Identity.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'ApiAuthorizationDbContext'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Domain.Identity.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'.

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aspnet core Identity custom ApiAuthorizationDbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208894/aspnet-core-identity-custom-apiauthorizationdbcontext)

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is in this part `IdentityUser<int>`
you dont need to add te `<int>`

you are inherit from IndentityUser which is not an int.

besides that i dont think you should change the actual primary key, just add one column with the value you want to store, because you would need to change almost everything that useses the primary key in the microsoft model in order to use it.