# Automapper issue with identityserver4 - MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map(System.Object)'

Tags: automapper, identityserver4

I using last version of IdentityServer 4

#### Issue / Steps to reproduce the problem

- Creating a new blazor webassembly app
- I scaffolded all the Identities files and customized
- and [custom ApiAuthorizationDbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208894/aspnet-core-identity-custom-apiauthorizationdbcontext) for blazor webassembly
- Install `Automapper v10` and `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyIn v8.0.1`

when I run project, in-browser give me 500 error :

`AuthenticationService.js:44 GET https://localhost:5001/connect/authorize?client_id=Web.Client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=code&scope=Web.ServerAPI%20openid%20profile&state=4b9b0120a48442a786b5bc8260c52f65&code_challenge=ViBkoIwumlfy_kg_y0bAh9uFsEByt2aKDOVUSREfARE&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&response_mode=query 500`

and in self-host console:

```
crit: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Unhandled exception: Method not found: '!!0 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map(System.Object)'.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map(System.Object)'.
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.PersistedGrantMappers.ToEntity(PersistedGrant model)
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore.StoreAsync(PersistedGrant token)
   at IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultGrantStore`1.StoreItemAsync(String key, T item, String clientId, String subjectId, DateTime created, Nullable`1 expiration)
   at IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultGrantStore`1.CreateItemAsync(T item, String clientId, String subjectId, DateTime created, Int32 lifetime)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator.CreateCodeFlowResponseAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator.CreateResponseAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointBase.ProcessAuthorizeRequestAsync(NameValueCollection parameters, ClaimsPrincipal user, ConsentResponse consent)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint.ProcessAsync(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map(System.Object)'.
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.PersistedGrantMappers.ToEntity(PersistedGrant model)
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore.StoreAsync(PersistedGrant token)
   at IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultGrantStore`1.StoreItemAsync(String key, T item, String clientId, String subjectId, DateTime created, Nullable`1 expiration)
   at IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultGrantStore`1.CreateItemAsync(T item, String clientId, String subjectId, DateTime created, Int32 lifetime)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator.CreateCodeFlowResponseAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator.CreateResponseAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointBase.ProcessAuthorizeRequestAsync(NameValueCollection parameters, ClaimsPrincipal user, ConsentResponse consent)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint.ProcessAsync(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

and in `https://localhost:5001/connect/authorize?client_id=Web.Client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=code&scope=Web.ServerAPI%20openid%20profile&state=4b9b0120a48442a786b5bc8260c52f65&code_challenge=ViBkoIwumlfy_kg_y0bAh9uFsEByt2aKDOVUSREfARE&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&response_mode=query` file:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map(System.Object)'.
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.PersistedGrantMappers.ToEntity(PersistedGrant model)
```

Stack:

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map(System.Object)'.

IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.PersistedGrantMappers.ToEntity(PersistedGrant model)
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore.StoreAsync(PersistedGrant token)
IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultGrantStore<T>.StoreItemAsync(string key, T item, string clientId, string subjectId, DateTime created, Nullable<DateTime> expiration)
IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultGrantStore<T>.CreateItemAsync(T item, string clientId, string subjectId, DateTime created, int lifetime)
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator.CreateCodeFlowResponseAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request)
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator.CreateResponseAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request)
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointBase.ProcessAuthorizeRequestAsync(NameValueCollection parameters, ClaimsPrincipal user, ConsentResponse consent)
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint.ProcessAsync(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Show raw exception details

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map(System.Object)'.
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.PersistedGrantMappers.ToEntity(PersistedGrant model)
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore.StoreAsync(PersistedGrant token)
   at IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultGrantStore`1.StoreItemAsync(String key, T item, String clientId, String subjectId, DateTime created, Nullable`1 expiration)
   at IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultGrantStore`1.CreateItemAsync(T item, String clientId, String subjectId, DateTime created, Int32 lifetime)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator.CreateCodeFlowResponseAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator.CreateResponseAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointBase.ProcessAuthorizeRequestAsync(NameValueCollection parameters, ClaimsPrincipal user, ConsentResponse consent)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint.ProcessAsync(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: You need an older AM. Or a newer Identity Server. See https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu another error `System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'GetAllAsync' in type 'IdentityServer4.Stores.InMemoryPersistedGrantStore' from assembly 'IdentityServer4, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f294d0afe402bb2b' does not have an implementation.'`

Comment: You seem to have version mismatches between your nuget references. Start from scratch with a working sample, or build yourself a simple test project.

Comment: I using Blazor Webassembly Individual user account with default Authentication

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Do not move backward, Do not downgrade, Upgrade**

It seems that the AutoMapper `10.0.0` has a bug, the solution to that problem was to upgrade AutoMapper to `10.1.1` version.

This version is very new, it released 4 days before the date of this answer.

Comment: What bug? :) There are no changes in the `Map` signature in 10.1.1.

Comment: the signature will not change, but I think the internal implementation has changed, so the bug has solved.

Comment: I don't see how the error message above is related to 10.1.1. It seems to me that smth else _also_ changed to make the error go away.

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference to the bug ? I see the error happing only while running in Linux(K8s) environments, but locally, on Windows I don't manage to reproduce.

 In my instance is not IdentityServer specific code, but the solution integrates with IdentityServer 4, and the issue start being present after moving to IS 4.1.2

Answer (score 13):

I had same issue because different project in the solution had different version of Automapper(9.0.0) and Automapper(10.1.1)

I changed all the projects within solution to have same dependencies. ie. Automaper(10.1.1)
It got solved

Answer (score 11):

I don't think it's related to identityserver but more the fact that there was 2 differents version of AutoMapper used.

I just had this issue in a solution with a few projects in it and yesterday I updated AutoMapper in one of them leaving another project with the old version.

Result, the application was broken.

I just updated the other project and it's now working fine.

Comment: This solved it for me, I had two projects in the same solution and one was using an older version. Once it was upgraded the issue went away.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue after adding AutoMapper to another project. I was using the same versions. `Identity 3.1.8`

`Automapper v10 and AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyIn v8.0.1`

I found the best solution for me is to rollback the Automapper version to 9 and the `DI` respectively.

Comment: Had similar issue for WPF application. And, the point was that project referenced different versions of `Automapper` related packages. Updated of NuGet packages for the entire solution helped to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just rolled back to the most used version 7.0.0 of 8/12/2019 and think are good now

Comment: In my case I had not explicitly added Automapper via NuGet, only AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection (latest 8.1.0) which has a dependency on AutoMapper 10. Just downgrading The DI package to version 7 (which has a dependency on AM 9) sorted everything out.

Comment: AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection version 8.1.1 confusingly has a dependency on version 10 of the main AutoMapper library. So I get this error if I don't update AutoMapper from 8.1.1 to version 10.

Answer (score 2):

Was buged by this lately. Turns out it was an AutoMapper missmatch between 2 consumers.

ProjA has dependency on AutoMapper version X and ProjB version Y.
ProjB Has dependency on AutoMapper version x.

When ProjA updateted its AutoMapper version ( from 9 to 10 for us ), without also updating the matched AutoMapper, to the same versionas the nuget coming from ProjB, ProjB was unable to operate, since the fetched mapper v10 had breaking changes with the v9 dll.

If you project references AutoMapper be carefull of braking changes between version, when using assembly binding to redirect dlls on published projects